# Plotly: Add parallel features in sunburst with sizes proportionate to parent class

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

In a plotly sunburst chart, I want to add multiple child classes to a parent class. I have tried assigning values to `names, parents, values` as shown [here](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#basic-sunburst-plot-with-plotlyexpress). But it returns a blank figure. I tried making a `path` variable (in the code below) but I am not sure how to name multiple direct children to a single parent class. Here is what I want-

[image]

And here is the code to reproduce-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent':['SA','SA','NA','NA'],
                  'country':['Brazil','Uruguay','USA','Canada'],
                  'total_vaccinations':[100,80,400,200],
                  'people_vaccinated':[40,20,100,80],
                  'people_fully_vaccinated':[8,4,11,11]})

px.sunburst(df, path=['continent','country'],values='total_vaccinations')
```

I want `people_vaccinated` and `people_fully_vaccinated` features as children to the respective countries depicting `total_vaccinations`. And I want them to be proportional in size according to their value. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, there are two ways to create sunburst plots with `px.sunburst()`. Either using the `path` variable or using the `names`, `parents` and `values` variables.

The first variant with the `path` variable is suitable for rectangular data, and thus not suitable for you, because you have missing values. Although there is a possibility for rectangular data with missing values, it requires that the parents of missing values do not have other entries [(plotly ref)](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#rectangular-data-with-missing-values).

Thus, you have to go with the second variant. As you have some leaves with identical names, you need in addition to `names`, `parents` and `values` also to define a list `ids` with unique strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


data = {
  'ids':['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV Brazil', 'PV Brazil', 'PFV Uruguay', 'PV Uruguay', 'PFV USA', 'PV USA', 'PFV Canada', 'PV Canada'],
  'labels': ['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV'],
  'parent': ['', '', 'SA', 'SA', 'NA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada'],
  'value': [0, 0, 100, 80, 400, 200, 8, 40, 4, 20, 11, 100, 11, 80]
  }

fig =px.sunburst(data, names='labels', parents='parent',  values='value', ids='ids')
fig.show()
```

The result will look like this:
[image: sunburst graph]

Comment: The solution works flawlessly! However when I make the color a continuous scale, the colors of `NA` and `SA` represent 0 (which makes sense as their value is assigned 0), whereas I would like them to represent the sum of countries. If I manually assign it, it leaves a big empty space, just like from (country:PV+PFV)

Comment: if you add the parameter `branchvalues="remainder"` you can assign non-zero values to NA and SA

Comment: I tried doing that but it does not give the desired solution. I asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956572/plotly-add-size-proportionate-child-features-in-sunburst-in-continuous-color-sc) for the same to be more clear.