# Plotly: Add size proportionate child features in sunburst in continuous color scale

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

This question is almost like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888158/plotly-add-parallel-features-in-sunburst-with-sizes-proportionate-to-parent-cla/67909466?noredirect=1#comment120084219_67909466) but with an important distinction, continuous color scale for which the same solution does not apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {
  'ids':['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV Brazil', 'PV Brazil', 'PFV Uruguay', 'PV Uruguay', 'PFV USA', 'PV USA', 'PFV Canada', 'PV Canada'],
  'labels': ['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV'],
  'parent': ['', '', 'SA', 'SA', 'NA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada'],
  'value': [0, 0, 100, 80, 400, 200, 8, 40, 4, 20, 11, 100, 11, 80]
  }

fig =px.sunburst(data, names='labels', parents='parent',  values='value', ids='ids', color='value',
                color_continuous_scale='Blues')
fig.show()
```

The code above reproduces this figure-

[image]

As you can see, the colours for `NA` and `SA` are that of the lowest end (as their value is zero) but their division proportion and size proportion to children is correct.

If I input their values the totals of their child classes i.e. replacing `value` with `'value': [180, 600, 100, 80, 400, 200, 8, 40, 4, 20, 11, 100, 11, 80]`, it produces this plot-

[image]

Now, the colours and proportion to each other are correct in this but the proportion to the child classes is not. How can I fix this? (I want the first figure but with root/parent nodes having colour as per size)

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that if the parent classes have values, the child classes will automatically be divided into non-proportionate smaller sectors even if the sum of child classes is equal to the parent class. So, the only way it is possible to have a somewhat desirable solution is for parent classes to have the actual value `0` and then manually assign them **colours** and **hoverlabels**. So, here comes the (almost ridiculous) workaround I have implemented.

#### Colours

The idea is to have a very large sequential colorscale that has hundreds of elements (or more, depending on the range you want). And then insert a desired color (I picked the midpoint of colorscale) to the start (minpoint) of the colorscale. This way, the `0` values will have a colour and the extremely large size of the colorscale will prevent all the other values from diverging much from their original colour.

1. You can generate the colorscale from [this](http://www.herethere.net/%7Esamson/php/color_gradient/) website. I didn't see any direct export or copy option so a quick copy into excel and then selecting the desired column from it did the trick for me.
2. Make a list of strings out of it. Add `#` as a prefix to each element.
3. Select the colour you want and add it to the front of the list. I selected the midpoint.
4. Pass the list to the colorscale argument of the plotting function.

```
# px.colors.sequential.Blues #Get first and last colour from this
my_colorscale = ["F7FBFF","F6FAFE","F5F9FD","F4F8FD","F3F7FC","F2F7FC","F1F6FB","F0F5FA","EFF4FA","EEF3F9","EDF3F9","ECF2F8","EBF1F8","EAF0F7","E9EFF6","E8EFF6","E8EEF5","E7EDF5","E6ECF4","E5EBF3","E4EBF3","E3EAF2","E2E9F2","E1E8F1","E0E7F1","DFE7F0","DEE6EF","DDE5EF","DCE4EE","DBE3EE","DAE3ED","D9E2ED","D9E1EC","D8E0EB","D7DFEB","D6DFEA","D5DEEA","D4DDE9","D3DCE8","D2DBE8","D1DBE7","D0DAE7","CFD9E6","CED8E6","CDD7E5","CCD7E4","CBD6E4","CAD5E3","CAD4E3","C9D3E2","C8D3E1","C7D2E1","C6D1E0","C5D0E0","C4D0DF","C3CFDF","C2CEDE","C1CDDD","C0CCDD","BFCCDC","BECBDC","BDCADB","BCC9DB","BBC8DA","BBC8D9","BAC7D9","B9C6D8","B8C5D8","B7C4D7","B6C4D6","B5C3D6","B4C2D5","B3C1D5","B2C0D4","B1C0D4","B0BFD3","AFBED2","AEBDD2","ADBCD1","ACBCD1","ACBBD0","ABBACF","AAB9CF","A9B8CE","A8B8CE","A7B7CD","A6B6CD","A5B5CC","A4B4CB","A3B4CB","A2B3CA","A1B2CA","A0B1C9","9FB0C9","9EB0C8","9DAFC7","9DAEC7","9CADC6","9BACC6","9AACC5","99ABC4","98AAC4","97A9C3","96A9C3","95A8C2","94A7C2","93A6C1","92A5C0","91A5C0","90A4BF","8FA3BF","8EA2BE","8EA1BD","8DA1BD","8CA0BC","8B9FBC","8A9EBB","899DBB","889DBA","879CB9","869BB9","859AB8","8499B8","8399B7","8298B7","8197B6","8096B5","7F95B5","7F95B4","7E94B4","7D93B3","7C92B2","7B91B2","7A91B1","7990B1","788FB0","778EB0","768DAF","758DAE","748CAE","738BAD","728AAD","7189AC","7089AC","7088AB","6F87AA","6E86AA","6D85A9","6C85A9","6B84A8","6A83A7","6982A7","6881A6","6781A6","6680A5","657FA5","647EA4","637EA3","627DA3","617CA2","617BA2","607AA1","5F7AA0","5E79A0","5D789F","5C779F","5B769E","5A769E","59759D","58749C","57739C","56729B","55729B","54719A","53709A","526F99","526E98","516E98","506D97","4F6C97","4E6B96","4D6A95","4C6A95","4B6994","4A6894","496793","486693","476692","466591","456491","446390","436290","43628F","42618E","41608E","405F8D","3F5E8D","3E5E8C","3D5D8C","3C5C8B","3B5B8A","3A5A8A","395A89","385989","375888","365788","355787","345686","345586","335485","325385","315384","305283","2F5183","2E5082","2D4F82","2C4F81","2B4E81","2A4D80","294C7F","284B7F","274B7E","264A7E","25497D","25487C","24477C","23477B","22467B","21457A","20447A","1F4379","1E4378","1D4278","1C4177","1B4077","1A3F76","193F76","183E75","173D74","163C74","163B73","153B73","143A72","133971","123871","113770","103770","0F366F","0E356F","0D346E","0C336D","0B336D","0A326C","09316C","08306B","08306B"]
midpoint = my_colorscale[int(len(my_colorscale)/2)]
my_colorscale.insert(0, midpoint)
my_colorscale = ['#'+x for x in my_colorscale]
```

#### Hoverlabels

Create a list that consists of the values of each sector and pass that list to `custom_data` parameter in the function. Then, call `fig.update_traces()` and pass `%{customdata}` to the `hovertemplate` parameter.

Here is the complete code-

```
# px.colors.sequential.Blues #Get first and last colour from this
my_colorscale = ["F7FBFF","F6FAFE","F5F9FD","F4F8FD","F3F7FC","F2F7FC","F1F6FB","F0F5FA","EFF4FA","EEF3F9","EDF3F9","ECF2F8","EBF1F8","EAF0F7","E9EFF6","E8EFF6","E8EEF5","E7EDF5","E6ECF4","E5EBF3","E4EBF3","E3EAF2","E2E9F2","E1E8F1","E0E7F1","DFE7F0","DEE6EF","DDE5EF","DCE4EE","DBE3EE","DAE3ED","D9E2ED","D9E1EC","D8E0EB","D7DFEB","D6DFEA","D5DEEA","D4DDE9","D3DCE8","D2DBE8","D1DBE7","D0DAE7","CFD9E6","CED8E6","CDD7E5","CCD7E4","CBD6E4","CAD5E3","CAD4E3","C9D3E2","C8D3E1","C7D2E1","C6D1E0","C5D0E0","C4D0DF","C3CFDF","C2CEDE","C1CDDD","C0CCDD","BFCCDC","BECBDC","BDCADB","BCC9DB","BBC8DA","BBC8D9","BAC7D9","B9C6D8","B8C5D8","B7C4D7","B6C4D6","B5C3D6","B4C2D5","B3C1D5","B2C0D4","B1C0D4","B0BFD3","AFBED2","AEBDD2","ADBCD1","ACBCD1","ACBBD0","ABBACF","AAB9CF","A9B8CE","A8B8CE","A7B7CD","A6B6CD","A5B5CC","A4B4CB","A3B4CB","A2B3CA","A1B2CA","A0B1C9","9FB0C9","9EB0C8","9DAFC7","9DAEC7","9CADC6","9BACC6","9AACC5","99ABC4","98AAC4","97A9C3","96A9C3","95A8C2","94A7C2","93A6C1","92A5C0","91A5C0","90A4BF","8FA3BF","8EA2BE","8EA1BD","8DA1BD","8CA0BC","8B9FBC","8A9EBB","899DBB","889DBA","879CB9","869BB9","859AB8","8499B8","8399B7","8298B7","8197B6","8096B5","7F95B5","7F95B4","7E94B4","7D93B3","7C92B2","7B91B2","7A91B1","7990B1","788FB0","778EB0","768DAF","758DAE","748CAE","738BAD","728AAD","7189AC","7089AC","7088AB","6F87AA","6E86AA","6D85A9","6C85A9","6B84A8","6A83A7","6982A7","6881A6","6781A6","6680A5","657FA5","647EA4","637EA3","627DA3","617CA2","617BA2","607AA1","5F7AA0","5E79A0","5D789F","5C779F","5B769E","5A769E","59759D","58749C","57739C","56729B","55729B","54719A","53709A","526F99","526E98","516E98","506D97","4F6C97","4E6B96","4D6A95","4C6A95","4B6994","4A6894","496793","486693","476692","466591","456491","446390","436290","43628F","42618E","41608E","405F8D","3F5E8D","3E5E8C","3D5D8C","3C5C8B","3B5B8A","3A5A8A","395A89","385989","375888","365788","355787","345686","345586","335485","325385","315384","305283","2F5183","2E5082","2D4F82","2C4F81","2B4E81","2A4D80","294C7F","284B7F","274B7E","264A7E","25497D","25487C","24477C","23477B","22467B","21457A","20447A","1F4379","1E4378","1D4278","1C4177","1B4077","1A3F76","193F76","183E75","173D74","163C74","163B73","153B73","143A72","133971","123871","113770","103770","0F366F","0E356F","0D346E","0C336D","0B336D","0A326C","09316C","08306B","08306B"]
midpoint = my_colorscale[int(len(my_colorscale)/2)]
my_colorscale.insert(0, midpoint)
my_colorscale = ['#'+x for x in my_colorscale]

value2 = [180, 600, 100, 80, 400, 200, 8, 40, 4, 20, 11, 100, 11, 80]

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {
  'ids':['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV Brazil', 'PV Brazil', 'PFV Uruguay', 'PV Uruguay', 'PFV USA', 'PV USA', 'PFV Canada', 'PV Canada'],
  'labels': ['SA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'Canada', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV', 'PFV', 'PV'],
  'parent': ['', '', 'SA', 'SA', 'NA', 'NA', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Uruguay', 'Uruguay', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada'],
  'value': [0, 0, 100, 80, 400, 200, 8, 40, 4, 20, 11, 100, 11, 80]
  }

fig =px.sunburst(data, names='labels', parents='parent',  values='value', ids='ids', color='value',
                color_continuous_scale=my_colorscale, custom_data=[value2])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{label}<br>%{customdata}')
fig.show()
```

Here is the output (notice the bottom of the colorbar :D)-

[image]

This is by no means a perfect solution as the colours for `NA` and `SA` are the same. I think this too could be solved though with a large enough colorscale and changing the value of one of those to `1` instead of `0` as that minor change would be unintelligible to the eyes on the graph, and adding a second color shade as the second element on the list `my_colorscale`.

I'm open to better solutions and I won't mark this as the answer.